# how to set the scale to logarithmic and linear when i right click on the particular figure in GUI matlab

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

I have created a Gui in matlab which has three axes and i would like to change the scale to log and linear by right click on the particular figure and select the scale options(1.logarithmic 2.linear). I tried using the UIcontextmenu. But i didn't get the result.

```
    firstcycle_mass = handles.Data1{1,1}(1:6392,1);
    firstcycle_ioncurrent = handles.Data1{1,2}(1:6392,1);

    replace_with_dot_firstcycle_mass = strrep(firstcycle_mass, ',','.');
    X1 = str2double(replace_with_dot_firstcycle_mass);

    replace_with_dot_firstcycle_ioncurrent = strrep(firstcycle_ioncurrent, ',','.');
    Y1 = str2double(replace_with_dot_firstcycle_ioncurrent);


            axes(handles.axes1);
         plotline= plot(X1,Y1,'r');
            xlabel('Mass [amu]');
            ylabel('Ion current [A]');
c=uicontextmenu;

 plotline.UIContextMenu = c;

    % Create menu items for the uicontextmenu
    m1 = uimenu(c,'Label','logarithmic','Callback',@setlinestyle);
    m2 = uimenu(c,'Label','linear','Callback',@setlinestyle);


        function setlinestyle(source,callbackdata)
            switch source.Label
                case 'logarithmic'
                    set(gca,'yscale','log')
                case 'linear'
                    set(gca,'yscale','linear')
        end
end
```

Comment: What version of MATLAB?

Comment: And what does `I didn't get the result` mean?

Comment: when i right click my mouse, nothing happens...

Comment: Are you right clicking on the line plotted on `handles.axes1`?

Comment: No.. i am just right clicking on the axes1....not exactly on the line

Comment: You have set `UIContextMenu` as a property of the line object here, not the axes. You need to click on the line.

Comment: Ya, i tried bt still it doesnt work. Do i need to change something in the button down function of axes1?

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sco1/85ada057e0e6593ba422) functions as expected. This is why we ask for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, so we don't have to play 20 questions and guess at what you have done and why it's not working.